# Typical dirt bike clutches - is there a norm?

Tags: automotive-engineering, transmission

I have several of the typical 49cc 2 stroke engines used for dirt bikes. They all have the same type of centrifugal clutch. Recently I have ordered a Honda GX-35 (4 stroke) engine and - what a surprise - it uses the same type of clutch. I am wondering, is there a standard for those clutches or why are they all compatible? Also are there clutches of the same format that engage quicker? For my Honda GX-35 I need to put like 25% throttle to engage the clutch at 4200 RPM, however I would like to have the clutch engage at like 2-3% throttle already. What do I have to look for to get something like this?

Comment: Change the masses and springs: that changes the reaction time. But think about the consequences.

Comment: Yea, obviously, but why can I unscrew a random clutch bell from a 2-stroke engine and put it on my honda GX-35 engine and it goes with 4200 RPM like you can read on the internet. There has to be some kind of (unwritten) standard, doesnt it?

Comment: Also maybe it is just my programmer me talking, but I cannot believe that people just use the same type of equipment just because it is convenient ;)

Comment: don’t they take chunks of code and re-use it? Just because it’s there. And, they do that even if it has a bug...

Comment: You mean because it turns up on a stackoverflow search? No.... it never happens.... ever!

Comment: well there was that old joke about older windows programs that would not run on the newer version but all the bugs would run fine... but that was a joke that was also used for just about every system...